# expected an indented block python

Tags: python

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
... print w, len(w)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print w, len(w)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>> print w, len(w)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
>>> for w in words:
... print w, len(w)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print w, len(w)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I'm learning Python though main doc.[This chapter](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)(4.2. for Statements) .But when i'm practicing it on UBUNTU TERMINAL it gave me above error ? what's that mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, your `print` statement needs to be indented since it is in a `for` loop

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
...     print w, len(w)
cat 3
window 6
defenestrate 12
```

In python, indentations are not simply for readability, they are a requirement. The following two are **NOT** the same thing

```
if 1==1:
print 'yes'   #incorrect indentation, not accepted by python
```

AND

```
if 1==1:
    print 'yes'   #correct indentation, accepted by python
```

Indentation is basically placing whitespaces before certain lines in your code with <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: ca you elaborate what is the indented mean ?

Comment: @samitha, Is that better?

Comment: Yes.I got it.Thanks.Do i want to do the same thing when i writing codes in the page (.py) ?

Comment: @samitha, Yes definitely, python anywhere. same rules.

Comment: @samitha, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.